# How to upload image to user profile using angular express multer mongoose

Tags: angular, mongodb, express

Hi i m uploading image using multer. when i choose image it is saving in the backend folder called uploads. Bt i want to save it in mongodb database and display that image on frontend using anguler. I dpnt no how to do. Please help to solve this.
here is my api.js

```html
// set storage engine
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, './uploads/')},
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now() + '.' + file.fieldname.split('/')[1])
    }
  })
   
  // initialize upload
  const upload = multer({ storage: storage })

 

router.post('/profile',upload.single('image'),  verifyToken, (req, res) => {
     res.json({
        imagUrl:'http://localhost3000/uploads'+ req.file.filename})
    const userId = req.userId;
    User.findOne({_id: userId}, (error, user) => {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error)
        } else {
         user.save({$set: {image: req.file}})
        res.status(200).send(user)
        }  
    })
})
```

here is my service.js

```html
private profileUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/profile/";
uploadImage(image: any) {
     const data = new FormData()
     data.append('image', image)
    return this.http.post<any>(this.profileUrl, data)
   }
```

here is my component.ts

```html
uploadImage(event: any) {
    
    this.auth.uploadImage(event.target.files[0])
    .subscribe((res) =>{
      console.log(res)
       this.imgUrl = res.imagUrl
    })
  }
```

here is my component.html

```html
<input type="file" id="imgUrl" class="form-control-file" (change)="uploadImage($event)">
               <img *ngIf="imgUrl" src="{{imgUrl}}" alt="imgUrl" height="200px">
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first i suggest, since u are using multer, u could just store The image path that is stored inside uploads folder in mongoose like req.file.path, and not storying the whole image as a file since it takes alot of storage and it’s not recommended to do so.
and in the server u can serve uploads folder as static (with express js)
please take a look into this to learn more.
https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html
https://github.com/expressjs/multer/blob/master/README.md

Answer (score 0):

I am not attaching any code example here because its not cleared which method you prefer to develop this feature,

There two methods if you want to store in mongoDB database,

1. GridFS

   - mongoDB reference docs, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/
   - recommending a demo, [uploading-files-to-mongodb-with-gridfs-and-multer-using-nodejs](https://dev.to/shubhambattoo/uploading-files-to-mongodb-with-gridfs-and-multer-using-nodejs-5aed)
   - [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3f5Q9wDePzY)
2. BSON

   - mongoDb reference docs, https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/
   - recommending a demo, [how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js](https://medium.com/@alvenw/how-to-store-images-to-mongodb-with-node-js-fb3905c37e6d)
   - [youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g5AIkcF8Mxw)

*(you can find both type of image upload examples and demo of node.js in below link)*

**General reference:** https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/2408370

**Difference:** GridFS. GridFS is a specification for storing and retrieving files that exceed the BSON-document size limit of 16 MB. ... Instead of storing a file in a single document, GridFS divides the file into parts, or chunks [1], and stores each chunk as a separate document.

**My Recommendation:** You can use GridFS, because its advance than BSON and no limitation.

Hope this helps.